# ERROR ITMS-90164: Invalid Code Signing Entitlements for 'com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier' Key

Tags: app-store, code-signing-entitlements, itmstransporter

I'm trying to upload my app to the App Store via Transporter App. My app is going to use iCloud to save some user data. But I'm getting this error while uploading:

> ERROR ITMS-90164: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements
>   in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained
>   in the provisioning profile. According to the provisioning profile,
>   the bundle contains a key value that is not allowed:
>   'MY_APP_IDENTIFIRE' for the key
>   'com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kystore-identifier' in 'MY_APP_NAME'."

[image: ERROR ITMS-90164 Image]

- I have iCloud enabled for the appID.
- I've recreated the provisioning profile.
- I've rebuilt the project several times.

My Entitlements are as follows:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>[ICLOUD_CONTAINER_IDENTIFIER]</string>
</array>

<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
<string>[APP_PREFIX].[BUNDLE_ID]</string>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone ending up here:
You should use TEAM_ID instead of APP_PREFIX for kvstore-identifier.

`<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
<string>[TEAM_ID].[BUNDLE_ID]</string>`